# Real-time bar chart in a Java applet

Tags: java

I want to display data and watch the bars move as the data comes in. Is there a way to do this with a java applet?

(I'm not married to the idea of an applet)

Comment: Do you want to do this on a web app or a desktop app?

Comment: Either would be fine. It's a very small project.

Comment: I lean toward web app, however.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/). It has a ChartPanel, which is a Swing component that can be added to an applet. If you update the DataSets of the charts the panel will automatically update. You will just somehow have to retrieve the data from the server as it comes in. It should be possible to use a HTTP connection to the web server and read it line by line and parse it for data that you add to the chart data. You will probably need some kind of queue in the server that receives data from a process that generates new data and writes it to the HTTP stream.